# Frequency of a word in a string

Tags: c, string

Alright, I was solving my assignment and in this particular program, the output for the word 'say' is displayed as 1 even though it occurs twice.

```
//Start
    # include <stdio.h>
    # include <string.h>
    int main()
    {
     char Str[100]="Martha! Why did you say that name? Please! Stop! Why did 
                    you say that name?", Words[100][100], Temp[100];
  int i, j, k, n, Count;
  j=k=0;
  //Accepting input
  //gets(Str);
  Str[strlen(Str)]='\0';
  //Copying Each and every word into a 2-D Array from the string
   for(i=0;Str[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
     if(Str[i]==' ')
      {
       Words[j][k]='\0';
       k=0;
       j++;
      }
     else
      {
       Words[j][k++]=Str[i];
      }
    }
  Words[j][k] = '\0'; //Null character for last word
  n=j;
  //Sorting the array of words
  for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
   {
    for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
     {
      if(strcmp(Words[i], Words[j])>0)
       {
         strcpy(Temp, Words[i]);
         strcpy(Words[i], Words[j]);
         strcpy(Words[j], Temp);
       }
     }
   }
  printf("\n");
  //Displaying frequecncy of each word

   for(i=0;i<n;i+=Count) //Incrementing by count to process the next word
    {
     Count=1;
       {
        for(j=i+1;j<=n;j++)
          {
           if(strcmp(Words[i], Words[j])==0)
            {
             Count++;
            }
          }
       }
      printf("%s\t%d\n", Words[i], Count); //Count is used to display the frequecncy of each word
    }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}//End
```

**Here is the output:**

```
Martha! 1

Please! 1

Stop!   1

Why     2

did     2

name?   2

**say     1**

that    2

you     2
```

As you see, the output displays the frequency of the word 'say' one even though it occurs in the string twice.
[Check the link for the output on the terminal?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmKHr.png)

Comment: You don’t take into account multiple spaces, newlines etc and you have a split string. Put it on one line and see what happens. Also `Str[strlen(Str)]=‘\0’` does nothing since `strlen()` already requires the null to be there and returns the index to it.

Comment: macos+clang -- worked fine.   You might want to break words on strings of punct|space...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`n` is not set up correctly.

With `n = j;`, conceptually this should be `n = j+1;` for `n` to represent `n` words and not the last index.

```
// n = j;
n = j+1;
```

Without the above change the array is not completely sorted as `n` is treated as the word count, yet it is 1-too-small.

Incorrectly sorted array is

```
Martha!, Please!, Stop!, Why, Why, did, did, name?, say, say, that, that, you, you, name?
```

---

Incomplete sort and now using `n` as the last index messed up frequency count as `"name?"` was found twice, yet not in consecutive order - thus jumping over the first `"say"`.

```
// for (j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
```

Repaired code output

```
Martha! 1
Please! 1
Stop!   1
Why 2
did 2
name?   2
say 2
that    2
you 2
```